# Rockshox 35 Gold RL weight?

Tags: fork

I am trying to account for weight differences between the Salsa Timberjack 29 [XT](https://salsacycles.com/bikes/timberjack/2021_timberjack_xt_29) and [GX](https://salsacycles.com/bikes/timberjack/2021_timberjack_gx_eagle_29) builds. They have 2.4 pounds difference. Primary differences are fork and XT/GX Eagle drivetrain.

I suspect the fork as a major contributor but I cannot find the weight of the Rockshox 35 Gold RL with 130mm travel listed anywhere. Has anyone measured this fork’s weight?

Comment: “Primary differences are fork and XT/GX Eagle drivetrain” The wheels are also different. I suspect it’s the wheels, fork and all the groupset components.

Comment: @Michael Yes you’re right, missed that. But it’s only hub difference. The rims and tires are the same. Surely this wouldn’t account for much?

Comment: The rear tyres are apparently also different? Can’t find the weight on the internet though. It’s really infuriating how manufactures refuse to provide even basic data. I guess all the little weight differences just add up. But it’s still surprising that there is more than a kg of difference for two very similar bikes.

Comment: @Michael yep, in typical Maxxis fashion, they have 100 different versions of the same tyre, and the one you are trying to find doesn't actually exist.  Assuming the 2.6 follows the same pattern as the 2.5WT and 3.0 then the 3C compound version on the lighter bike should be saving somewhere between 0.1-0.2lbs of the 'missing' weight: https://www.maxxis.com/uk/tyre/minion-dhf/

Answer (score 1):

Found it. For others looking, this video weighs the fork:

Measured: 2258g

The Marzocchi Bomber Z2 is 2043g, which only accounts for 20% of the weight difference between the models.

FYI same person weighs the Z2 here:

Comment: How much is the Marzocchi Bomber Z2 on the other bike? I’ve found 2030 grams.

Comment: @Michael you’re likely right, lots of small differences add up. But still seems like a large difference. Still 1.8 pounds unaccounted for.